# using array of object in firebase

Tags: firebase

Firebase recommended to storing data in object .

But I found very hard to fit what I want.

```
 - I want to get the size of object.
 - The first object
 - and the last object.
```

does firebase support this on object?

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to retrieve the size of the object without storing (and updating) it separately at the moment.

You can retrieve the first object in the list easily using `ref.startAt().limit(1)` and the last object using `ref.endAt().limit(1)`.